# Breaking down complex Prisma queries in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, prisma

I’ve got a Next.JS app. I want to render a todo feed on the homepage, but also the user page. I'm a bit stuck on how to break down my Prisma queries.

I fetch a big data object using getServerSideProps and pass this to the page component (and using react-query to hydrate and do re-fetching, but not relevant now)
- getRecentTodos (includes todos) for my homepage
- getUserDetailsByName (includes todos) for the user page

```
export type getRecentTodos = ReturnType<typeof getRecentTodos> extends Promise<
  infer T
>
  ? T
  : never
export const getRecentTodos = async (recentItemsAmount = 20) => {
  return await prisma.todos.findMany({
    where: { done: true },
    select: {
      id: true,
      userId: true,
      content: true,
      done: true,
      createdAt: true,
      attachments: true,
      todoReplies: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          userId: true,
          content: true,
          todoReplyLikes: true,
          todoId: true,
          user: { select: { name: true, displayName: true, image: true } },
        },
        orderBy: { createdAt: 'asc' },
      },
      todoLikes: {
        select: {
          user: true,
        },
      },
      user: {
        select: {
          name: true,
          displayName: true,
          image: true,
        },
      },
    },
    orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
    take: recentItemsAmount,
  })
}
```

```
export const getUserDetailsByName = async (username: string) => {
  return await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      name: username,
    },
    select: {
      name: true,
      displayName: true,
      bio: true,
      location: true,
      twitter: true,
      image: true,
      createdAt: true,
      todos: {
        select: {
          id: true,
          content: true,
          userId: true,
          done: true,
          updatedAt: true,
          createdAt: true,
          attachments: true,
          user: true,
          todoLikes: true,
          todoReplies: {
            take: 30,
            orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
            select: {
              id: true,
              userId: true,
              todoId: true,
              createdAt: true,
              content: true,
              user: true,
            },
          },
        },
        take: 30,
        orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
      },
      projects: true,
    },
  })
}
```

Both queries return ‘todos,’ but they can return it in a slightly different way. The todo feed component expects certain properties to be available
- E.g. displayName on todoReplies
- But on getUserDetailsByName the displayName might not be part of the response or it’s nested one layer deeper or something

- How to keep this from getting complex very fast?

  - You more or less want to select todos in your queries the same way (returning the same and omitting the same, apart of some things like order)
  - But manually keeping these things in sync over lot’s of queries qet’s complex quickly

**Possible solutions?**

- Should I break the getServerSideProps into multiple fetches?

  - So instead of one ‘getUserDetailsByName’ which has todos as a relationfield included

    - fetch user details
    - fetch todos
  - This would mean I also have to write more react-query code for refetching etc… because you are dealing with multiple objects. But it does seperate concerns more.
- Using Typescript to catch it in my codebase when a function tries to access a property which is not returned from that specific Prisma query? (I’m just now starting to see the possibilities of Typescript for stuff like this)
- Should I just standardize the way the todos get created in a prisma query with a function and include that function inside of the Prisma queries?  you can include like:

```
const todoSelect = {
  id: true,
  userId: true,
  content: true,
  {.......}
  user: {
    select: {
      name: true,
      displayName: true,
      image: true,
    },
  },
}

export type getRecentTodos = ReturnType<typeof getRecentTodos> extends Promise<
  infer T
>
  ? T
  : never
export const getRecentTodos = async (recentItemsAmount = 20) => {
  return await prisma.todos.findMany({
    where: { done: true },
    select: todoSelect,
    orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
    take: recentItemsAmount,
  })
}

const userSelect = {
  name: true,
    {......}
  todos: {
    select: todoSelect,
    take: 30,
    orderBy: { createdAt: 'desc' },
  },
  projects: true,
}

export const getUserDetailsByName = async (username: string) => {
  return await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      name: username,
    },
    select: userSelect,
  })
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a combination of the last two options, using Typescript to catch any issues and standardizing the todos creation in Prisma queries to make it easier to keep the queries in sync.